# Low latency on simple graph activation

Tags: database, latency, db4o

I'm using db4o as backend for a project that look like semantic wiki.
My main concern is why performances are so low ?

**Here is the context :**

*The application use the openJdk6 & db4o-v8.1. The model is about twenty classes in four levels of inheritence, there is activatable collections, reference, uuid, index, etc...*

*By using sys-time logs I found that the time is spend in the part of manipulation of objects. For 30 activations or updates, the application took 1.1s on average(less than 1Kb of data at commit time). I have checked the memory(dump), just small part off the graph are load(my database is about 20K objects and 20Mb) as expected from transparent activation. I almost never use querys, always relations activation.*

*I'm using the client-server on the same host. The db-server is the example one we can found on the db4o website. Client-server kill some performance, but is requiere for concurrency. The host rely an fc storage that enable around 300iops.*

- What can be done to improve performance, reduce latency ?
- Do I miss something ?
- Is there any trick I should know ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have follow the manual, then the problem come from your data-model
or use usage of it.
If you already have down all possibles optimization for the usage, the last way
is the more re-factoring of the data-model; If you don't have... just do it now.

So the short answer : *don't use inheritance*, keep relation chains as short as possible.

Longer answer :

- *Dynamism cost a lot.* Class inheritance add dynamism to the method resolution and object resolution at activation.

In an hibernate/sql like db; An inheritance can be see as join on tables, loading an object imply loading multiple line in a mush table as inheritance level. So the speed is limited by the join requiere (and the join conditions).

In db4o when you navigate throw an object the decision to use all fields of the objects is done on the user level part; so all the objects pointers are load is case of activation of a field. So all parts of the object model must be load from the database(for the activated object). This is very similar to what happen in hibernate/sql db.

- To avoid scanning to mush parts of model, and load to mush activation pointer, we can **rewrite the model** a little.
  Just remove every inheritances relations and replace them with field pointing to corresponding objects.

If A extends B then add a field in B that point on A and remove the extends relation. Then use transparent activation to navigate from A to B as need. This trick is efficient in many domain, database or not. It work because in complex graph relationship we rarely use all fields of objects in one computation.

- Another solution to improve performance is to use shorter activation path, to achieve this you will need a massive change in your model and computation; A way to this is to use fast native query, not only the transparent activation.

For a good night reading on performance in object database you can also look at objectDB. There is the same problems as in db4o.